# Powershell SMO job.alter() doesn't update the SQL Steps

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am working to update the agent job with data based on certain string found under job step. I can see the SMO finding the string displaying the replacement object in memory. But when I try to alter the final output

```
$AgentJob = Get-SqlAgentjob -ServerInstance $InstanceName | where Name -Like "somestring*"
```

it doesn't work in updating the actual agent job steps.

```
Foreach ($steps in $AgentJob.jobsteps)
{
   $steps.Command -Replace("CurrentString1","$NewString2") 
   $steps.Alter()
   $steps.Command -Replace("CurrentString2","$NewString2") 
   $steps.Alter()
   $steps.Command -Replace("CurrentString3","$NewString3")
   $steps.Alter()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually updating the command text, you're just outputting it.

Try

```
$steps.Command = $steps.Command -Replace 'CurrentStringX, $NewStringX
```